# OLE Automation in Java does not send e-mail from all computers

Tags: java, ole, email

I am working on creating some applications to distribute with a small team where I work.  Mostly just simplifying and creating some consistency with some processes.  As such, I have created an application to send out an e-mail to a different team.   The application sends an e-mail through outlook after collecting some information from the user.

The application works fine for me, but a co-worker who has been helping me do some bug testing has been unable to send the e-mail.  I am unsure if it is because I have Outlook 2013 whereas he has Outlook 2010(I have a newer laptop and he hasn't gotten the upgrade yet).  If that is the case, can I enable functionality for both?

Below is the method called when the user sends the e-mail:

```
public void sendEmail()
{
    String strName = txtName.getText();
    String strTis = txtTisFile.getText();
    String strCDs = txtCDs.getText();
    String strWorkID = txtWorkReqID.getText();
    String strQueue = txtQueue.getText();

    if (strCDs.length() == 0)
        strCDs = "N/A";             

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    //This should start outlook if it is not running yet
    OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
    site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

    // Now get the outlook application
    OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
    OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);

    OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */).getAutomation();

    setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
    setProperty(mail, "Subject", "XXXX - " + sdf.format(date) + " Work Request Number: " + strWorkID);
    //setProperty(mail, "From", "XXXX@XXX.com");
    setProperty(mail, "To", "XXXX@XXXX.com");
    if (ccITOC == true)
        setProperty(mail, "CC", "XXXX@XXXX.com");

    setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody", "<html><body>Hello, <p> <p>Output is located in: " + strQueue + "<p>" + strTis + ".lis<p>Work Request #: " + strWorkID + "<p>#CDs: " + strCDs + "<p>Thank you,<p>" + strName + "<p> IT Operations Center</body></html>");

  if (null != filePath) {
      File file = new File(filePath);
      if (file.exists()) {
          OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
          invoke(attachments, "Add", filePath);
      }
  }

    invoke(mail, "Send");
}

public void clearInfo()
{
    txtQueue.setText("");
    txtWorkReqID.setText("");
    txtName.setText("");
    txtTisFile.setText("");
    txtCDs.setText("");
}

private static OleAutomation getProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
    Variant varResult = auto.getProperty(property(auto, name));
    if (varResult != null && varResult.getType() != OLE.VT_EMPTY) {
        OleAutomation result = varResult.getAutomation();
        varResult.dispose();
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command,
        String value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
            new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command));
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command, int value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
            new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
}

private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
        String value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
}

private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
        int value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
}

private static int property(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
    return auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { name })[0];
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you leave the From: field blank? Have you tried with a non-blank From field?

Comment: Ehh, just never deleted it.  It's commented out so it shouldn't have any affect, correct?

Comment: I am not sure if Outlook will fill in the From address automatically if it is empty. Futhermore, perhaps this also may cause problems when someone has multiple email accounts configured. Have you tried your script with a non-empty from field?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  I am unsure if leaving the From field blank. I logged into a co-workers laptop using my credentials and attempted to use the application.  Where it worked on my laptop with Outlook 2013, it doesn't work while logged into the other laptop, running Outlook 2010.

Comment: I did find https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240794 that mentioned checking the registry for the appropriate ProgID for the following line of code:
    OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");

Comment: Follow-up.  I changed the progID to Outlook.Application.14 and had a coworker try it again, but no luck.

Comment: You don't have any error checking in your code, that way it will be extremely hard to find the real problem.

Comment: Yea,

I'm not sure where I could insert any to catch an error of this nature.

Also, I did remove the comment for the "from" line and had a coworker try it.  Still no luck.

Comment: Good code consist for 50% of error checking (wild guess) and you have zero error checking, assuming everything will run smoothly and perfect, like there will never be an error, which is not realistic. For instance, your call OleClientSite looks very important and has no error checking. Everything that can return errors should be checked and preferably logged or warned.

Comment: I believe I am beginning to track down the issue.  It seems the application doesn't like to play nice once compiled into a runnable jar and/or wrapped into an exe.

I can run it from eclipse and it runs fine, but once running outside of that it no longer plays nice.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If Eclipse libraries can do it, you can do it too. Just do error checking and find your bug or stick to eclipse.

Comment: I added error checking and based on the error, I found the issue.

I was using the 64-bit version of SWT, which apparently doesn't play well with Outlook as it is a 32-bit executable.  I switched to a 32-bit JRE and SWT and all is well.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So now you've learned how important error checking is... :-)

Comment: Indeed, I did.  As it turns out and for whoever finds themselves with a similar issue.  It turns out that because Outlook is a 32-bit application.  I needed to use the 32-bit version of SWT(I was not).